# How to design custom spinner

Tags: android, xml

I want to design a custom spinner. I tried many examples but got no results. I want to make a border with a drop down image. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design custom design of spinner like as

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_weight=".28"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/drop" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

for border of spinner you add this drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="@color/darkGray" />
```